# what's the difference between .out and .log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I never bothered to find this out. Let's see I have a java web application running called "myapp" What's the difference between myapp.out and myapp.log file?

.log file can be rotated according to log4j.properties setting, how about .out file? do I need to set up the rotation policy for it as well?

Comment: .out is for System.out. You shouldn't be using System.out.println() in a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `.log` and `.out` is the last three letters of the file name. Log4j and System.out can be redirected to either of them.  if you are using log4j properly you should get much if any output to System.out so you shouldn't need to rotate it.

If your application doesn't use log4j particularly well and writes *alot* to System.out, you may need to rotate the file, but this will require you to restart the application.

Answer (score 5):

.out will print all logs related to your java application deployed whereas
 .log file will print all logs related to weblogic server like startup.stop,deployment etc....

.out will have standard shell output where the instance was started and it will have mostly
 Notice and above log level will be written on it. .log will have the server logs along with
 all sub system logs too.